# On showing the equality between a filtration $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge 0}$ and a twice time-changed filtration $(\tilde{\mathcal F_t)}_{t\ge 0}$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, filtrations

Let $A$ be a strictly increasing continuous process which is adapted to a right-continuous filtration $(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge0}$. We also suppose that $A_\infty=\infty$. For $t\ge0$, let $C_t=\inf\{s\ge0:A_s>t\}$. Under the preceding conditions, it is known that $\forall t\ge0$, $C_t$ is an $(\mathcal F_s)_{s\ge0}$ stopping time, $C$ is a strictly increasing continuous process with $C_\infty=\infty$, and that $A_{C_t}=C_{A_t}=t$ for $t\ge0$. We can therefore define $\hat{\mathcal F}_t=\mathcal F_{C_t}$ for $t\ge0$. Again, it is known that for $t\ge0$, $A_t$ is an $(\hat{\mathcal F}_s)_{s\ge0}$ stopping time, and we define $\tilde{\mathcal F}_t=\hat{\mathcal F}_{A_t}$. Is it true that $\forall t\ge0$, $\mathcal F_t=\tilde{\mathcal F}_t$?\

Firstly, we can start off by noticing that the fact that $\mathcal F$ is right-continuous implies that $\hat{\mathcal F}$ and $\tilde{\mathcal F}$ are also right-continuous. Furthermore, we have that $C_\infty=C_{A_\infty}=\infty$ hence $\mathcal F_\infty=\hat{\mathcal F}_\infty=\tilde{\mathcal F}_\infty$. It's now tempting to use the formal definition of $\tilde{\mathcal F}_t=\{B\in\hat{\mathcal F}_\infty:B\cap\{A_t\le s\}\in\hat{\mathcal F}_s\}$ and the fact that we have $\{A_t\le s\}=\{t\le C_s\}$, but this doesn't seem to yield anything interesting. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How about $\tilde{\mathcal F}_t=\hat{\mathcal F}_{A_t}=\mathcal F_{C_{A_t}}=\mathcal F_t$, since $C_{A_t}=t$ almost surely ?

Comment: Maybe it's that easy, but I'm a little bit careful of filtrations indexed by stopping times. I agree that we should, for example, have $\hat{\mathcal F}_{A_t}=\mathcal F_{C_{A_t}}$ in which case we're done, but how is this proven exactly? I doubt that it can be shown that trivially though, because your proof doesn't seem to use right-continuity explicitly, which I think is a requirement for the result to be true

Comment: I believe that right continuity is supposed to be used to prove $A_{C_t}=C_{A_t}=t$.

Comment: Those equalities are due to the fact that $A$ is strictly increasing